# ¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "A pesar de ser bonito, nunca dormí en el palito"?

Tags: coloquialismos, expresiones, argentina

Escuchando [*Nos volveremos a ver*](http://www.cmtv.com.ar/discos_letras/letra.php?bnid=56&tmid=383&tema=NOS_VOLVEREMOS_A_VER), de Andrés Calamaro, una frase me resulta curiosa: "A pesar de ser bonito, nunca dormí en el palito".

He buscado por foros de internet el significado de dicha expresión, sin éxito.
En algunos foros mencionan que la frase hace alusión a que, a pesar de ser atractivo, nunca tuvo relaciones homosexuales, digamos, tomando "el palito" como alusión al miembro viril.
En otros foros he leido que "el palito" es un coloquialismo usado para referirse a la prisión, pero aún así, no encuentro mucho sentido dado el contexto de la frase completa.

No sé si es una expresión argentina o si se trata de algo que se inventó Calamaro en esta canción.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La letra no es de Calamaro sino de Jorge Larrosa, autor del libro *Postales tumberas*. *Tumbero* significa relativo a la cárcel. La letra de la canción tiene temática *tumbera*.

El *palito* es un sector de la cárcel donde duermen los que no son admitidos en el pabellón por los otros presos, como se describe en el siguiente párrafo, que es parte de una descripción de la cárcel de Villa Devoto, en Buenos Aires:

> Cada pabellón o cuadro es un rectángulo que mide 35 por 7 u 8 metros de ancho, a ambos lados tiene grandes ventanas, muchas de ellas sin vidrios, con filas de camas en cada lado, quedando un pasillo en el medio donde se colocan las mesas, utensillos, alimentos, formándose lo que se conoce como “ranchada”. Durante la noche este pasillo queda cubierto de colchones y cobertores por el hacinamiento existente. En la mitad del pabellón hay una especie de jaula donde se encuentra el celador y luego de esta reja se ubica el comedor (“**el palito**”) con una gran mesa y al costado de ésta otras “ranchadas” donde viven quienes no pueden ingresar al pabellón porque trabajan o porque son “mal vistos” y sometidos a golpizas.-

Comment: después de leer tu respuesta, excelente por cierto, investigué más sobre Jorge Larrosa, su relación con Calamaro y su libro y ahora ésta canción tiene muchísimo más sentido que antes para mí, dadas las referencias antes mencionadas. Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

El *palito* es donde duermen los que no tienen cama, como los pájaros en una jaula. Los bonitos a veces no la pasan bien y se quedan sin cama teniendo que ir al *palito* a dormir.